# Auth0 using my own database for CRUD after user logs in

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, oauth-2.0, auth0

I'm using Auth0 for login purposes and signup purposes. It's seamless. But I have a MySQL database that holds all the information for my website and the profile that logs in. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around retrieving the profile information after logging in with Auth0.

I was thinking. After the user logs in. Do I use the Auth0 API on my backend to validate the user to then retrieve info from MySQL DB? I'd like to stick to the free version of Auth0. I guess I'm not fully understanding how to CRUD MySQL after Auth0 login.

This is my code for the login process:

```
 login(redirectPath: string = '/') {
    // A desired redirect path can be passed to login method
    // (e.g., from a route guard)
    // Ensure Auth0 client instance exists
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
      // Call method to log in
      client.loginWithRedirect({
        redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}`,
        appState: { target: redirectPath }
      });
    });
  }
```

Every time I google using my own database after logging in Auth0 wants me to use their services. I'd like to use Node.js with MySQL after the user logs in to perform CRUD actions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will have the user login via auth0, then a token will be issued. This token can be validated on your backend, and the user id (from auth0) will be stored to create a new user, or used to lookup and existing user.

You can connect an existing database to use as the identity provider, but that is not a free feature.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. So understanding this correctly, the user logs in and returns a access token (I've finally found a way to get this). Then I send the bearer token given by the API and the Access Token (from the login) to my backend. The backend validates the Access Token (and the API bearer token). Correct? ------- Also, I've been looking for a way to validate the access token in Node.js. Doesn't seem like an easy thing to search for. Do you happen to have a link @DanWoda?

Comment: The only way I can get an access token for the API is if I use the client secret no? I'm looking at the Test tab. IF I follow how the test example. I technically don't even have to be logged into Auth0 to access the API. right? I guess I'm not fully understanding the flow.